# can't find why react tutorial code does not work

Tags: reactjs

I learn react -  i copy some code and i trying to see if its work. 
I get an exception that i can't understand what its says and how to continue

The code:

```
var Game = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
   return { winner: this.getRandomCell(), score: 0 };
},

  getRandomCell: function() {
    return _.random(this.props.count - 1);
  },

  clicked: function(i) {
    if ( i === this.state.winner ) {
      this.setState({
        score: this.state.score + 5,
        winner: this.getRandomCell()
      });      
    } else {
      this.setState({
        score: this.state.score - 5
      });
    }
  },

  renderButton: function(i) {
    var cls = "cell ";
    if ( i === this.state.winner ) {
      cls += "winner";
    } 
    return <button className={cls} onClick={this.clicked.bind(this,i)}></button>
  },

  render: function() {    
    var btns = [];
    for ( var i=0; i < this.props.count; i++ ) {
      btns.push(this.renderButton(i));
    }       

    return (
  <div>
    <p>Score: {this.state.score}</p>
    <div>
      {btns}
    </div>  
  </div>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<Game count={9} />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

problem is in the line :

```
       return <button className={cls} onClick={this.clicked.bind(this,i)}></button>
```

The exception is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

Comment: change the extention of the file to .jsx if its a .js file or .tsx if its a .ts file

Comment: have you set up babel?

Comment: `React.createClass` is deprecated and so is  `React.render` if you lint your code, you will be able to catch these warning without having to compile first. `vscode` has multiple plugins for linting `reactjs` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createClass()` is no longer in React package, it as been moved to `create-react-class` package, the purpose of this function is to write [React code without ES6](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html).

If you plan to use ES6 you should refactor your code to a function or a `React.Component` class ([Official React intro tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html))

Edit: about your exception try to add a label to your button :

```
<button className={cls} onClick={this.clicked.bind(this,i)}> MyButton </button>
```